# How to exclude missing data in specific columns in R

Tags: r, database, na, missing-data

I have a `df` with 15,105 `rows` and 127 `columns`. I'd like to exclude some specific colunms' rows that have `NA`. I´m using the following command:

```
wave1b <- na.omit(wave1, cols=c("Bx", "Deq", "Gef", "Has", "Pla", "Ty"))
```

However, when I run it it returns with 19 `rows` only, when it was expected to return with 14,561 `rows` (if it should have excluded only the `NA` in those specific `colunms` requested). I'm afirming this, cause I did a subset on the `df` in order to test the accuracy of the missing deletion.

Does anyone could help me solving this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Since you probably want the whole `data.frame` returned it might be best to do: `wave1[rowSums(is.na(wave1[,c("Bx", "Deq", "Gef", "Has", "Pla", "Ty")])) == 0, ]`

Comment: `na.omit` does **not** have an argument `cols`. I have just tried it and it does nothing. You are probably removing all `NA` values from all columns.

Comment: Yes. It was removing from all colunms.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is not efficient but it could work:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(NA,3), B = c(NA,2,3),C=c(1,NA,2))
df
   A  B  C
1 NA NA  1
2 NA  2 NA
3 NA  3  2
```

It removes only the rows which have missing values for the columns B and C:

```
df[-which(is.na(df$B)|is.na(df$C)),]
   A B C
3 NA 3 2
```

Comment: You don't need the `which`. You can just do `!(is.na(df$B)|is.na(df$C)`

Comment: It worked, but the right argument is & instead of | so it supposed to be like this: df [ !(is.na(df$B) &! is.na(df$C), ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete.cases`

```
> df[complete.cases(df[, -1]), ]
   A B C
3 NA 3 2
```